# What would be returned if a method return type is of a self created class?

Tags: java

Here I created a return type of class Point. Also What do I write after "return" statement

```
  class Point{
    int x=2;
    int y=4;

  }

  class TwoPoint{

    public static void main(String args[]){
       Point obj1=new Point();
       Point obj2=new Point();
       System.out.println(obj1.x);
       System.out.println(obj2.y);

   }

       public Point newFunction(int a,int b){
       }


 }
```

Comment: It will return a Point, like you told it to. After the return put a Point. Although here it looks like you're attempting to define a function inside another function (main), which isn't OK.

Comment: what? everything in java returns **Object**, **primitive type** or **void**.

Comment: This code would not compile. 1. Java does not allow methods inside methods. 2. Even assuming that `newFunction` is outside of `main`, it does not return an instance of `Point` (it has an empty body). To get a meaningful answer, please update your question with a good example and phrase your question clearly.

Comment: 1. Where you got sth like this? 2. Here, you are right.

Comment: These are basics. You should realy look deeper into object oriented programming and Java. Maybe read a book or make some tutorials (i don't want to be mean, but obviously you don't understand basic knowledge)

Comment: @Nivasi have read about returning int, String ,double etc. but not for the self created Class.for eg. return String in a methods return a string.I dont understand what does return Point mean??

Comment: Please read/learn from notes first before putting question here thank you. here what you should know http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very basic concept of Java, or really any Object Oriented Programming (OOP) language and you can find it in just about every book and tutorial out there.

But since the question is here forever branded in Internet history I'll provide an answer to it.

Your method:

```
public Point newFunction(int a,int b){
}
```

Must return a Point object, just like you told it to when you set the return type to Point.

This means it will return a Point object. An object can contain all sorts of data and method etc. so you're returning a lot more than just an `int` or `char` or anything.

I've modified your code so it actually does something and this is an example of how you return a Point (or any other object) and what that means.

```
class Point{

    int x;
    int y;

    public Point(int a, int b){
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }
    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }
    public int getY(){
        return y;
    }
  }

  class TestCode{

    public static void main(String args[]){
       Point obj1 = new Point(1, 2);
       Point obj2 = newFunction();
       System.out.println(obj1.x + " " + obj1.y);
       System.out.println(obj2.getX() + " " + obj2.getY());
   }

       public static Point newFunction(){
           return new Point(9, 9);
       }    
 }
```

This creates `obj1` and its a new Point with x and y values. Then it creates obj2 and sets it equal to whatever `myFunction()` returns. Since we know `myFunction()` HAS to return a Point object, this works.

Then `myFunction()` creates a new Point object and uses the values 9 and 9. Then you print the values to see how they are affected.